# Compare arguments from two uses of the same macro

Tags: macros

I need to have a macro that looks at its previous use and compares the first arguments, then prints additional text if those arguments are the same.

For example

```
\mycommand{Michael}{Hello, John}

Michael and John shake hands.

\mycommand{Michael}{How are you today?}\\
\mycommand{John}{I'm good, how are you, Michael?}\\
\mycommand{Michael}{Good, thank you.}
```

would print something like:

> Michael: Hello, John.
>
> Michael and John shake hands.
>
> Michael **(again)**: How are you today?
>  John: I'm good, how are you, Michael?
> Michael: Good, thank you.

I initially thought I might be able to use something like `\renewcommand{\charactername}{#1}` in the macro definition, but that would need to be expanded for the comparison to work. Any ideas?

**EDIT**

@egreg answered below with a solution that worked first go. If you need to reset the stored argument (in my example, the names of characters) you can use `\gdef\dialogue@remember{}`.

Comment: Look at some acronym package (acro, glossaries), they all contains commands to print something different at the first usage.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer — It's the subsequent usage that needs to change, and only for sequential use of the same command with identical first arguments.

Comment: It is the same principle: The command does something different depending on previous usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store in memory the previous speaker:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdftexcmds} % for engine cross-compatibility

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mycommand}[2]{%
  #1\ifnum\pdf@strcmp{\mycommand@remember}{#1}=\z@ ~(again)\fi
  \gdef\mycommand@remember{#1}%
  : #2%
}
\def\mycommand@remember{} % initialize
\makeatother

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} % just for the example

\begin{document}

\mycommand{Michael}{Hello, John}

Michael and John shake hands.

\mycommand{Michael}{How are you today?}

\mycommand{John}{I'm good, how are you, Michael?}

\mycommand{Michael}{Good, thank you.}

\end{document}
```

[image]

An extended version where the main command has a *-variant that clears the remembered character.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\dialogue}{smm}
 {
  \IfBooleanT { #1 } { \str_gclear:N \g__experimenthouse_speaker_str }
  \experimenthouse_dialogue:nn { #2 } { #3 }
 }

\str_new:N \g__experimenthouse_speaker_str

\cs_new_protected:Nn \experimenthouse_dialogue:nn
 {
  #1 % speaker
  \str_if_eq:VnT \g__experimenthouse_speaker_str { #1 } { ~(again) }
  \str_gset:Nx \g__experimenthouse_speaker_str { \tl_to_str:n { #1 } }
  :~#2
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} % just for the example

\begin{document}

\dialogue{Michael}{Hello, John}

Michael and John shake hands.

\dialogue{Michael}{How are you today?}

\dialogue{John}{I'm fine, how are you, Michael?}

\dialogue{Michael}{Fine, thank you.}

\dialogue{Michael}{Fine, thank you.}

\dialogue*{Michael}{Fine, thank you.}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: — Wow! This does exactly what I wanted. Extremely helpful. Thank you very much!